# how to build AST while LL(1) parsing

Tags: javascript, parsing, compiler-construction, stack, abstract-syntax-tree

I am writing a LL(1) parser, and the parser working perfectly fine.
but all the goal of a parser is process tokens and produce an AST.
I wonder how to manage an object to build AST while doing parsing.

my code:

```
  while (tokens.length) {
    let currentRule = rulesStack.pop();
    let currentToken = tokens[0];

    if (isTerminal(currentRule)) { // `S`->nonTerminal, `2`->Terminal
      if (currentRule === currentToken) tokens.shift();//[`3`,`+`,`2`] => [`+`,`2`]
      else {
        // throw error
        return;
      }
    } else { // currentRule is not Terminal
      let nextRule = parseTable[currentRule][currentToken];
      if (nextRule) { // if exists
        if (nextRule[0] === 'epsilon') {
          // do nothing
        } else rulesStack.push(...nextRule);
      } else {
        
        // throw error
        return;
      }
    }
  }
```

What is the correct way to build AST in this parser?

Comment: One possible algorithm is in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54751222/1566221

Comment: What do you mean by "popping an appropriate number of values from the value stack" ?

Comment: One for every child of the node being created. Or, iow, one for each symbol on the rhs of the production.